# Is it possible to set dynamic frame-rate with cocos2d-x?

Tags: android, text, rendering, cocos2d-x

I want to write a text reader which has special effects with cocos2d-x, so the most time the graph will be static. If I use cocos2d-x, it's just heavily consuming battery power.

So is it possible to adjust cocos2d-x's frame rate by coding? And how? I want to reduce frame rate when text's static, and increase frame rate when paging up or down.

Or any good idea for this goal on Android? (Page turning animations and more efficient text rendering.)

Comment: In cocos2d-iphone there is CCDirector animationInterval which defines the max framerate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change frame rate using cocos2d::Director::setAnimationInterval method.

https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-x/blob/1361f2c6195ce338a70b65c17e3d46f38e6bcce2/cocos/base/CCDirector.h#L140-L141

```
/** Set the FPS value. */
virtual void setAnimationInterval(double interval) = 0;
```

However, I wonder, if you set framerate low, your C++ code wasn't called immediately when paging up or down because the framerate is low. So you might need to modify onDrawFrame to call Cocos2dxRenderer.nativeRender immediately when user touched the screen.

https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-x/blob/1361f2c6195ce338a70b65c17e3d46f38e6bcce2/cocos/platform/android/java/src/org/cocos2dx/lib/Cocos2dxRenderer.java#L84-L106

```
@Override
public void onDrawFrame(final GL10 gl) {
    /*
     * No need to use algorithm in default(60 FPS) situation,
     * since onDrawFrame() was called by system 60 times per second by default.
     */
    if (sAnimationInterval <= 1.0 / 60 * Cocos2dxRenderer.NANOSECONDSPERSECOND) {
        Cocos2dxRenderer.nativeRender();
    } else {
        final long now = System.nanoTime();
        final long interval = now - this.mLastTickInNanoSeconds;

        if (interval < Cocos2dxRenderer.sAnimationInterval) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep((Cocos2dxRenderer.sAnimationInterval - interval) / Cocos2dxRenderer.NANOSECONDSPERMICROSECOND);
            } catch (final Exception e) {
            }
        }
        /*
         * Render time MUST be counted in, or the FPS will slower than appointed.
        */
        this.mLastTickInNanoSeconds = System.nanoTime();
        Cocos2dxRenderer.nativeRender();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, you really gave me some valuable tips!